# Octopus Deploy Prevent a Package from Deploying to another environment

Tags: continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

I am working with Octopus deployment tool. We have a situation where **we should not promote the binaries from DEV to QA**. This is due to the reason where some features are still in development. We have another branch MAIN from where all the feature will be released. From here we will be generating build and deploying to QA and PROD.

In order to keep the build environment intact, we need to build and deploy only to DEV and should not be promoted.

I thought of creating a separate project specifically for DEV environment.

Before proceeding with this approach, I wanted to know if there any other better solution.

Raaj

Answer (score 3):

You could create a separate lifecycle that has only the DEV environment in it to prevent it from being promoted. Octopus has a feature called channels which allows you to create releases that are only able to be deployed to the defined environments within that unique lifecycle.

https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/channels